# Grails params.max returns a map

Tags: grails, pagination

I am new to grails and have just started developing applications in work. The first thing that i wanted to do is create a gsp with two tables, each table having pagination functionality. With a research I found that there is a plugin called remotePagination that uses ajax to update a tables pagination. The problem that i am having is that the 'params.max' and 'params.offset' value is a map of two strings rather than just a string value. On opening the page the 'list' closure is called and with the correct values set for the max and offset, lets say 10. On the second call, when the ajax closure is called the max and offset values are each held within a map as follows:

```
params.max = [10,10]
params.offset = [10,10]
```

The code I am using is as follows:

Controller:

```
def list = {
    params.max = Math.min(params.int('max') ?: 10, 100)
    [bookInstanceList: Book.list(params), bookInstanceTotal: Book.count()]
}

def ajaxListBooks = {
    params.max = Math.min(params.int('max') ?: 10, 100)
    render(template: "bookList", model:[bookInstanceList: Book.list(params), bookInstanceTotal: Book.count()])
}
```

list.gsp

```
<%@ page import="com.intelligrape.Book" %>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
  <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book')}"/>
  <title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]"/></title>
  <g:javascript library="prototype"/>
 </head>

 <body>
   <div class="nav">
     <span class="menuButton"><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a>
    </span>
    <span class="menuButton"><g:link class="create" action="create"><g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]"/></g:link></span>
   </div>

   <div class="body">
     <h1><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]"/></h1>
     <g:if test="${flash.message}">
       <div class="message">${flash.message}</div>
     </g:if>
   <div id="repoList">
            <g:render template="bookList"/>
   </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

_listBooks.gsp

```
<%@ page import="com.nmi.uk.sw.subzero.Book" %>

<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>

        <util:remoteSortableColumn property="author" title="${message(code: 'book.author.label', default: 'Author')}" update="repoList" action="ajaxListBooks"/>
        <util:remoteSortableColumn property="name" title="${message(code: 'book.name.label', default: 'Name')}" update="repoList" action="ajaxListBooks"/>
        <util:remoteSortableColumn property="price" title="${message(code: 'book.price.label', default: 'Price')}" update="repoList" action="ajaxListBooks"/>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <g:each in="${bookInstanceList}" status="i" var="bookInstance">
        <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

            <td><g:link action="show" id="${bookInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: bookInstance, field: "author")}</g:link></td>

            <td>${fieldValue(bean: bookInstance, field: "name")}</td>

            <td>${fieldValue(bean: bookInstance, field: "price")}</td>

        </tr>
    </g:each>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="paginateButtons">
    <util:remotePaginate total="${bookInstanceTotal}" update="repoList"
                                      action="ajaxListBooks"
                                      pageSizes="[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]" />
</div>
</div>
```

The above code is based on the sample application for the remotePagination tutorial. It isn't that different. I created it just to see if the plugin would work before I integrated it into my application.

I would like to know if any one else has come across this problem and if there is a solution to it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your `_bookList.gsp`, there is an error in `<util:remotePaginate` tag:

```
pageSizes="[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]"
```

`pageSizes` should be a map, not a list, like:

```
pageSizes="[10:'10 Per Page', 20: '20 Per Page', 50:'50 Per Page',100:'100 Per Page']"
```

Comment: Could this be the cause of the params.max being a map and not a single value? I will correct it and get back to you.

Comment: Just corrected it, it didn't stop the problem. The params.max and offset are still maps.

Comment: [10,10] is a list, not a map. How do you find this params value?